# Windows 8 Tile does not update

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

The following code worked when I followed the tutorial using a new project:
http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/09/hellotiles-simple-c-xaml-application.html

However, I am unable to get the application's tile to update when I plug-in the same code to my real project.

1. I have rebuilt the package.
2. I have uninstalled and redeployed the app.
3. I have updated the wide logo image file.
4. I have verified that the same code works when creating a new project.
5. I have verified the app manifest as suggested by the linked tutorial.

How does this work fine in one solution but not the other?

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();


        ClearTileNotification();
        SendTileTextNotification("Why isn't this working!");
    }

    void ClearTileNotification()
    {
        // the same TileUpdateManager can be used to clear the tile since 
        // tile notifications are being sent to the application's default tile
        TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Clear();
    }

    void SendTileTextNotification(string text)
    {
        // Get a filled in version of the template by using getTemplateContent
        var tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWideText03);

        // You will need to look at the template documentation to know how many text fields a particular template has       

        // get the text attributes for this template and fill them in
        var tileAttributes = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        tileAttributes[0].AppendChild(tileXml.CreateTextNode(text));

        // create the notification from the XML
        var tileNotification = new TileNotification(tileXml);

        // send the notification to the app's default tile
        TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileNotification);
    }
```

Comment: have you tried putting the call to `SendTileTextNotification` somewhere other than the page's constructor? Like at the OnNavigatedTo or OnLoaded event.

Comment: 2 things:
1. Please paste the XML produced (break before the .Update() call and watch the XML and c/p it here.
2. Log out, log in, and make sure the code does not run inside the Simulator. I have found that the simulator totally breaks on displaying live tiles - when I do stuff with live times, I have to log off/log on often to see it working.